# AD reverse DNS zone sharing between subdomains

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dns-zone, reverse-dns

We have Active Directory infrastructure with one domain and several subdomains. Each subdomain has its dedicated subnets. All DNS servers on DCs have appropriate reverse zones, integrated in Active Direcrory. All works ok.

Now, we have a new network `10.0.20.0/24` for some special **users of subdomains**. And we need to split this network into parts for subdomains:

- `10.0.20.0/28` - for users of subdomain `ONE.ACME.LOCAL`;
- `10.0.20.16/28` - for users of subdomain `TWO.ACME.LOCAL`;
- and so on.

Computers must be able to register their PTR records automatically in apropriate zones on DNS servers within their domain; these records must be available on any DNS server in the forest.

**My question is:** How should reverse zone `20.0.10.in-addr.arpa` be configured on each [sub]domain's DNS server, for updating and synchronizing across the forest?

Should/must this zone be integrated into Active Directory or not?

Should/must Zone transfers/Update notifications be enabled on DNS servers?